# Get NavigationProperty on OData does not work

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

The goal is to retrieve an object already loaded with their NavigationProperties:

## Problem

Even informing `$expand` on OData URL, the **navigation property is not loaded!**

[image: Retrive object]

> Full image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JL3DG.png

If you try to **navigate to the property**, an **error is displayed!**

[image: Error OData on NavigationProperty]

> Full image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FIEZ.png

## Code

**Class**

```
public class Regional : EntityNome
{
    public virtual ICollection<Pessoa> Contatos { get; set; }
}
```

**Config**

```
modelBuilder.EntitySet<Regional>("regionais");
modelBuilder.EntitySet<Pessoa>("pessoas");
```

## API Version

> Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi -> 5.0.0-beta1-130514
>   Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client -> 5.0.0-beta1-130514
>   Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core -> 5.0.0-beta1-130514
>   Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData -> 5.0.0-beta1-130514
>   Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Web... -> 5.0.0-beta1-130514

Comment: do you have a method called GetContatos in your controller?...by default, odata routing conventions look for method with this name..

Comment: That was the problem. Thank you!